# How to convert extracted strings with multiple months into dates in Polars?

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-polars

I have data similar to the df below. I am trying to convert each column to a date column, but since there are two months in the original string, I am having trouble using polar's `strptime` or `cast` functions to extract any month or year. I know how to grab the specific month's as shown below, but each thing I've tried (`.strptime(pl.Date, "%B/%B %Y)`, `.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%B/%B %Y)` etc) before and after the extract function, any combination of the date formatting) has not been working. If you have any pointers that would be appreciated!

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "January/February 1994",
            "November/December 1996",
            "May/June 1999",
            "March/April 2005",
        ]
    }
)


out = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("name").str.extract(r"(\w+)\/").alias("start_month"),
    pl.col("name").str.extract(r"\/(\w+)").alias("end_month"),
    pl.col("name").str.extract(r"(\d+)").alias("year"),
)


print(out)
```

```py
shape: (4, 4)
┌────────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ name                   ┆ start_month ┆ end_month ┆ year │
│ ---                    ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ str                    ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ str  │
╞════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ January/February 1994  ┆ January     ┆ February  ┆ 1994 │
│ November/December 1996 ┆ November    ┆ December  ┆ 1996 │
│ May/June 1999          ┆ May         ┆ June      ┆ 1999 │
│ March/April 2005       ┆ March       ┆ April     ┆ 2005 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could probably do with a warning/mention in the docs.

The underlying parsing library requires a `day` to be present: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12427

You can manually prepend/insert `1` into the data and add `%d` to the format string.

```py
df.with_columns(
    start = ("1 " + pl.col("name").str.replace("/.* ", "")).str.to_datetime("%d %B %Y"),
    end = pl.col("name").str.replace(".*/", "1 ").str.to_datetime("%d %B %Y")
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ name                   ┆ start               ┆ end                 │
│ ---                    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ str                    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ January/February 1994  ┆ 1994-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1994-02-01 00:00:00 │
│ November/December 1996 ┆ 1996-11-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1996-12-01 00:00:00 │
│ May/June 1999          ┆ 1999-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1999-06-01 00:00:00 │
│ March/April 2005       ┆ 2005-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2005-04-01 00:00:00 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it recommended to name columns this way as opposed to using `alias`? I have been focusing on the docs (as a learning exercise, but also since I know it's being updated).

Comment: Adding a comment to show that this is how I would get the date as a number `year=("1 " + pl.col("name").str.replace("/.* ", "")).str.to_datetime("%d %B %Y").dt.year()`

Comment: @AdrianFletcher I don't believe there is any recommendation with regards to naming. (I just personally find it easier to read) `.alias()` is required in certain situations e.g. if the column name is not a valid Python identifier (contains a space, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `pl.Date/pl.Datetime` and a date is required in the string as of now, Something like below can help you.

```py
out.with_columns(
    ((pl.col("year")  + '-' + pl.col("start_month") + '-01').str.to_date("%Y-%B-%d")).alias("start_date"),
    ((pl.col("year")  + '-' + pl.col("end_month") + '-01').str.to_date("%Y-%B-%d")).alias("end_month"),
)
```

Comment: I didn't write that exact syntax, I was just explaining that those were different things I tried out. I will update my question.

Comment: Additionally, I picked @jqurious 's answer since it leverages the column we started with (name). This answer would require us to create intermediate columns that won't be used.